# when i remove rejectWithValue from the code the thunk is running else it is not running, i think the middleware is not correct

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
    import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
    
    const initialState = {
      productList: [],
      Rejected: false,
      Pending: false,
    };
    
    export const productDataApi = createAsyncThunk(
      "product/Card",
      async ({ rejectWithValue }) => {
        console.log("in thunk");
        try {
          const res = await fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL}`);
          const result = await res.json();
          console.log("result", result);
          return result;
        } catch (err) {
          rejectWithValue(err);
        }
      }
    );
    
    const productSlice = createSlice({
      name: "product",
      initialState,
      reducers: {},
      extraReducers: (builder) => {
        builder
          .addCase(productDataApi.pending, (state) => {
            state.Pending = true;
          })
          .addCase(productDataApi.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            console.log(action.payload);
            state.productList = action.payload;
          })
          .addCase(productDataApi.rejected, (state, action) => {
            state.Rejected = true;
            state.Pending = true;
          });
      },
    });
    
    export default productSlice.reducer;
    
    
    import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
    import productSlice, { productDataApi } from "./actions/productSlice";
    
    const store = configureStore({
      reducer: {
        product: productSlice,
      },
      middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => {
        getDefaultMiddleware({
          thunk: {
            extraArgument: {
              productDataApi,
            },
          },
          serializableCheck: false,
        });
      },
    });
    
    export default store;
```

The above code is used for calling and handling a api in react with the help of createAsyncThunk but I am unable to use rejectWithValue facility of the thunk . I don't know why?
i tried to use rejectWithValue and the middleware for thunk , i am expecting that the rejectWithValue should be working with the proper middleware for thunk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change you thunk with this and try.

```
export const productDataApi = createAsyncThunk(
      "product/Card",
      async (_, { rejectWithValue }) => {
        console.log("in thunk");
        try {
          const res = await fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL}`);
          if (!res.ok) {
            throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
          }
          const result = await res.json();
          console.log("result", result);
          return result;
        } catch (err) {
          return rejectWithValue(err.message); // Use rejectWithValue to pass an error message
        }
      }
    );
```